# Is there any way to scroll a ListView to a particular item in expandable layout?

Tags: android

I have an expandable layout which uses animation (Expand/Collapse). It's working fine. But when I select an item in it, it again shows top view instead of selected view. So finally what I need is how to scroll an expandable layout item to a particular view.

Comment: Expandable layout is any library?

Comment: no,its a custom layout that implements animation

Comment: How does this layout work? Does it collapse when you select an item but show the wrong item? Why not use a Spinner?

Comment: @vinodkumar On clicking any item in listview, it scrolls up?

Comment: A ListView won't scroll up if the bottom of the list is visible. Also, it won't automatically scroll selected item to the top. Try smoothScrollToPosition() on item click...

Comment: yes.i need to stop scroll on that situation.